# In-Page Analytics Issue w/ WordPress Site

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have implemented Google Analytics in the footer of my Wordpress site. On my homepage, I have a section where I show several posts in a  category. For some reason, when I log into my Google Analytics account and select in-page analytics, I cannot see any clicks on these posts.

I am sure that there should be some clicks on it. Is it possible that because these posts are coming from Wordpress custom fields, Google Analytics in-page analytics is not registering the clicks?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default in-page analytics can't see when one page element has multiple destinations or track buttons, menus, and actions driven by JavaScript.

You can consider implementing enhanced link attribution:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The in-page analytics is unable to track page element which has  multiple destinations or track buttons, menus, and actions ran by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check does your google analytics code work?
The google analytics should be placed in the header

Next, you should enable enhance your In-page analytics by adding this line in your GA code (enhanced link distribution - you can search it on Google):

```
ga(‘require’, ‘linkid’, ‘linkid.js’);
```

This is enough condition for your in-page analytics report work correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this be selecting "**admin**", then "**property setting**", then scroll down to the bottom of the page and turn on "**use enhanced link attribution**".

I suspect there may also be an issue with the placement of your Google Analytics tracking code. Make sure it's place before the closing header tag. There are also several Google Analytics plugins you could add to make sure your tracking code is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check if your ip is blocked or not in google analytics admin setting and also check you browser for gaoptout should not be installed in it.
Try to check these in google chrome after installing plugin "Page Analytics" and if you still not getting success then try to do this with google tag manager.